# trying to figure out how to write this with arrays

Tags: php

here is the code im having trouble with

```
$key = array(
"0" => "sss",
"1" => "wst",
"2" => "sfv",
"3" => "lac",
"4" => "sgv",
"5" => "lgb",
"6" => "ant"
);

$urls = array(
"0" => "http://www.sarmenhb.com/index.php?key=",
"1" => "http://www.navidoor.com/index.php?key=",
"2" => "http://www.worldexchange.com/index.php?key=",
"3" => "http://www.iaddesign.com/index.php?key=",
"4" => "http://www.iadesignandstudio.com/index.php?key=",
"5" => "http://www.redlineautoleasing.com/index.php?key="

);

for($a=0;$a <= count($urls);$a++) {
foreach($key as $keys) {
print $urls[$a].$keys[$a]."<br/>";

}
}

print "<br/><br/>";
```

i am trying to make the output look like this:

```
http://www.sarmenhb.com/index.php?key=sss
http://www.navidoor.com/index.php?key=sss
http://www.worldexchange.com/index.php?key=sss
http://www.iaddesign.com/index.php?key=sss
http://www.iadesignandstudio.com/index.php?key=sss
http://www.redlineautoleasing.com/index.php?key=sss

http://www.sarmenhb.com/index.php?key=wst
http://www.navidoor.com/index.php?key=wst
http://www.worldexchange.com/index.php?key=wst
http://www.iaddesign.com/index.php?key=wst
http://www.iadesignandstudio.com/index.php?key=wst
http://www.redlineautoleasing.com/index.php?key=wst

etc including all key values included as a value the the param key
```

ive removed the origional urls to prevent url hacking but how can i print an output like that?

the output i keep getting is key=s or key=w  the whole key value isnt displaying. along with an error of Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in D:\wamp\www\MVC\t.php on line 32

please help

thank alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($key as $string)
{
    foreach($urls as $address)
    {
        echo $address . $string . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: whoa makes sense. i feel such an idiot for including the key values inside the foreach arrays.. thanks alot

Comment: This answer is sufficient, but does it really need 3 upvotes?

Comment: If people like the answer sure. I don't care because I've already hit my cap.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply do two foreach statements:

```
foreach($urls as $url) {
  foreach($keys as $key) {
    print $url.$key."\n";
  }
}
```

I also recommend you to pluralize the name of your arrays for simple readability, check the output [here](http://codepad.org/fiPYqVny).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're printing `$keys[$a]`. $keys is a string from your array, and $a would just get a single character. You can select characters in strings the same way you select variable from array.

If you remove the square brackets it should work.

```
print $urls[$a].$keys."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the foreach loop and change $keys[$a] to $key[$a].